# How to emulate a socket connect timeout in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

In MacOS, I used to go with the following solution:

```
 import socket
 import time
 server = socket.socket()
 server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 7777))
 time.sleep(5)
 server.listen(1)
```

If another socket tries to connect to this address, it will be hung up until `server` calls `listen`.

But this is not the case in Linux, trying to connect before the `listen` call results in `Connection Refused` immediately.

So is there a better way to emulate connect timeout when testing?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Linux/Mac issue? and not Python versions.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe The Python version (2.7) is the same in both cases.

Comment: What are you _testing_ - a) the behavior of the client when the server doesn't listen, b) how long the client waits for the connection, or c) something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use poll or select. It returns until n seconds , which it is specified by you, or when it is writable, which means connectable for clients.
http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=poll#multiprocessing.Connection.poll

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of what you're testing, but you perhaps could go ahead and do an accept, and then sleep - you'll appear to get a connection in the client, but it doesn't do anything useful (for a while).  Or play with your firewall settings :)